# MongoDB: Modify a field from a document using a function

Tags: mongodb

The documents in my collection have the following format:
{ word: 'apple', number: 5 }

I want to increment the value of number from a javascript function. Yes, I know you can do that with a simple upsert, but I'm planning to do this for arrays and more complicated decisions that can't expressed by operators in a single upsert. This is just a simplified example.

What I've tried so far:

```js
db.a.find({word:'test'})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53c98ff18b95662af1148ad7"), "word" : "test", "number" : 5 }

db.a.find({word:'test'}).forEach(function(entry) { 
    inc: entry.number, 5; 
    print("test", entry.number);
})
```

test 5
(but it should be 10)

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: After formatting your code it's pretty clear why it isn't working as it's not valid JavaScript.  That said, I don't really understand what you're trying to do, either.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm trying to do this: $inc: {num: 5}, but from a javascript function, on every document that matches the find query.

Comment: Why don't you simply use var new_number = entry.number + x; and then update the documents with this new number. Thanks

Comment: But is there a way to update the same document the function is working on without making an additional update call? (which would essentially require a new query)

Comment: To persist your change to the database, you have to call `save` or `update`.

Comment: I'm not sure but findAndModify might do the update as the cursor moves.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.runCommand({
  findAndModify: "people",
  query: { name: "Andy" },
  sort: { rating: 1 },
  update: { $inc: { score: 1 } },
  upsert: true
})
```

As per my comment above. This should work in bulk operations as opposed to an update on each foreach iteration.